# Use result of group concat in subquery Mysql

Tags: mysql

hello I would like to use result of rows in `subquery`

```
group_concat(TI2.entry_id)
```

result of this is for **example** two ids `102,414` 
and this is display in results.

But when i try to use this rows in another query

```
SELECT   (SELECT  sum(transaction_item.item_price) from transaction_item where transaction_item.entry_id IN (group_concat(TI2.entry_id))) AS new
```

i got `sum` only for **one id**.

Any idea whats wrong here, using another query for this is not an option

Comment: This won't work. `in` needs separate values but `group_concat` returns just one string

Comment: yeah that it can values be splited?

Comment: This query is nonsensical. It would not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using nest  query in where clause

```
  SELECT  (SELECT  sum(transaction_item.item_price) from 
  transaction_item where transaction_item.entry_id IN 
  (select group_concat(entry_id) from transaction_item group by entry_id))
  AS new
```